# Bash; how can I retrieve everything after "_foo " in a line of text from file?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a properties.txt which includes information needed by my bash script.

Each line in that file is a single piece of information, and I preface each line with "_foo " to help grep find the information needed.

What I found so far is I can use grep to find the line with the information I need like this:

```
doge$ grep -n "_version " properties.txt
```

This outputs:

```
1:_version 1.1.0-release
```

How can I remove "_version " and store just "1.1.0-release" into a variable?

*preferably the solution will use built-ins found on almost every system by default*

Comment: If you want to work it on _almost every system_, you should drop the `--color=always`.  Also, your grep would return a line which looks like i.e. `17:_option newest_version`, which is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: It is very hard (impossible) ti find a solution with only 1 example line. Questions here: I spacing of the line always the same? Tabs or real spaces? Single or multi blanks?  Second part without blanks? Is the word to skip always the same?

Comment: @Wiimm Every line in the file will have the same syntax `_propertyID propertyValue`

That is a only single space character in between.
The syntax of the properties file can be modified to suit the code's expectation; it was designed the way it is now arbitrarily.

The current plan is the propertyValue will never have spaces outside of quotes.

@user1934428 i removed --color=always. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter Expansion

```
var='1:_version 1.1.0-release'; echo "${var##* }"
```

In your case, you can add a `Command Substitution` `$( )` to capture/save the output of the command and you can save it in a variable.

```
var=$(grep --color=always -n "_version " properties.txt)

echo "${var##* }"
```

Ok you can remove the color but it should not hurt also. That P.E. is not restricted to bash it should work on ay POSIX compliant shell.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I just started learning shell scripting and I have a lot to learn about parameter expansion syntax.

Thank you!

Comment: Good to know, also the `$( )` is called `command substitution` It captures/save the output of a command so you can assign it in a variable. I will Update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -n 's/_version //p' properties.txt`

This works by replacing each occurrence of `_version` with the empty string, and then only printing lines where that replacement was made.

Also, if it will always occur at the beginning, you can use `^` to prevent false positives.